# Сохранить фото из превью ссылки в телеграмме

Tags: python, telegram

[image: Пример отправленного сообщения]

Есть способ вытащить фотографию из такого сообщения, отправленного боту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. По API не получится. Можно получить лишь URL - он находится в объекте `message.enities`.

Важно понять, как Telegram получает превью ссылки. В случае с Facebook это делается посредством парсинга мета-тега `og:image`.

Comment: Но картинка может оказаться разной для разных регионов - не факт, что ты получишь ту же картинку, что и телеграм.

Comment: @Qwertiy другого способа я не вижу. Разбирать исходники клиентов - такое себе удовольствие.